# Granting permission to Sharepoint site/folder using Microsoft Exchange Distribution List/Group

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, distribution-lists

I have a scenario.

In my organization we use Microsoft Exchange Distribution Lists of users. Now I have created a SharePoint site (2013), I would like to use these distribution lists to grant permissions to SharePoint site /folders.

SharePoint seems to be recognizing the groups but when added the error says `Sorry, you are not allowed to share this with external users.` Although it is an internal mailer group.

These distribution lists are not AD distribution groups, although it acts like one, that I can simply change the same to Security Groups. Also note, I can't change the distribution list to a security group any how.

Please help me out here, is there any way I can start incorporating these exchange mailer list into SharePoint security model?

Answer (score 1):

No, they must be security groups to be used in permissions. Distribution lists cannot be used for security.

Comment: Yes that's exactly my problem, I was hoping if there is any work around solution. I can't change my mailers (DLs) to security groups, but is there any solution related to exporting the contacts from the mailer list and populate the Sharepoint security groups?